# How to get clicked bar chart tooltip data?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a bar chart where on a click of any bar, the data is displayed in a tooltip. I need the tooltip data in the `onClick` function.

Following is my code for the bar chart:

```
var tool = new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: true,
            labels: {
                fontColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
            },
            position : 'bottom'
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: title 
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{stacked: true,barPercentage: 5.0,
                categoryPercentage: 0.2}],
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: true,
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true 
                    },
                    barPercentage: 0.3
                }]
        },
        events: [ "click"],
        onClick: function(event, array){

            console.log("tool.data:",tool.tooltip);

        }

    }
});
```

[image]

I want the data in my click function like "missed", "medium", 78.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following **`onClick`** function to get tooltip­*'s* data :

```
onClick: function(event, element) {
   var activeElement = element[0];
   var data = activeElement._chart.data;
   var barIndex = activeElement._index;
   var datasetIndex = activeElement._datasetIndex;

   var datasetLabel = data.datasets[datasetIndex].label;
   var xLabel = data.labels[barIndex];
   var yLabel = data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[barIndex];

   console.log(datasetLabel, xLabel, yLabel);
}
```

also, you would need to set the **`hover`** mode of chart to `nearest` to get it working properly :

```
hover: {
   mode: 'nearest'
}
```

see a [**working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/1gzhnv37/).

Comment: @grunt but i am getting element[0] as undefined on my machine if i use your onClick function.

Comment: HOW?? As you can clearly see it's working perfectly fine on the given example.. make sure you're using the latest version of ChartJS (2.7.1)